# How to thicken a border of a shape

Tags: java, swing

When I click on a shape, in order to show "selection", I want to call a method `drawSelected` that will repaint the shape to show that it's selected. Something like this: https://gyazo.com/6e115bdca55aaecd70ebada7e046475d with how the square portion gets thicker.

In order to do that I need a border which I was able to figure out how to do by doing this:

```
// Set paint to the random color
g2.setPaint(getColor());
g2.fill(rectangle);
// Set the border of shape to black
g2.setPaint(Color.black);
g2.draw(rectangle);
```

But now when I click on a rectangle, the method that shows selection uses translate still and I get this: https://gyazo.com/07857f6782c3a32dc90946e79736374d where only the top and left get thicker.

I know the bottom and right are being draws as well, its just since they are filled with another color they overlap the previous rectangle so you don't see it.

My question is, how do I change the thickness of a border to where instead of translating a shape, I can just redraw the shape with a thicker border to show selection?

Comment: We cannot help until you give us more information as what are you using to draw. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can help you easily and they are not trying to understand the mystery that your question has.

Comment: Use Graphics2D.setStroke to a larger stroke

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, the best way is to redraw with a thicker border :

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
g2.setPaint(Color.black);
g2.draw(rectangle);
```